# Checking the sanity of a URL in an iOS app

Tags: ios, security, html-sanitizing

Here is a question I am facing. I would like to offer my users a way for checking the sanity of a given URL, inside an iOS app.

We all know when we surf on the internet, that not all sites are clean of viruses, malware or other ill-intended beasts. As much as possible we want to avoid these places. So when a user types in a URL, or gets it via some other means, she/he may want to run some checking.

I have done some research on the subject and found out [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) that seems to be a possible solution to use. I already know that someone will come up and say that the question of choosing between VirusTotal and MalwarePartial is not fit for this site, because dependant on opinions or preferences. But I do not intend to ask about VirusTotal or anyone else in particular. I only want to know if there is a standard way or best practice for this task: ***checking the sanity of a URL in an iOS app***.

Comment: You need to clarify your question (don't post comments). What exactly do you mean by "sanity" when it comes to checking a URL? Be specific and clear about what you really need to do.

Comment: I just edited the post.